# I need remote access to my MyTouch 3G Slide using a web interface with no access to the phone

Tags: backup, remote-control, remote-access, auto-start

I have a MyTouch 3G slide that is currently in Missouri and I am in North Carolina.  I have my Google Play account information and access to a PC.  The phone is not password locked but it is plugged in and has signal, no WiFi.  There are some apps I've seen that can install and as long as you accept the permissions in Google Play it will install and auto run without user interaction.  I've tried AndroidLost but I cannot get a stable enough connection to get the files and information I need.  Basically, I would like to access my SMS, MMS, phone logs, pictures and my stored files.  I thought maybe the AndroidLost App Launcher would help but to no avail.  I know all the phone info like IMEI and IP address using AndroidLost.  I just need an app that will activate and register itself with the phones gmail or by me sending an SMS with an activation code and it receives it.  Not that this may matter much but I'm stationed in Missouri and I'm in Fort Bragg right now for a school and being able to interact with my phone using my browser is detrimental to me right now, thank you in advance for any ideas!